# An efficient way to check all data in a collection one by one (nodejs, mongoose)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**The problem to solve**
I'd like to read all documents in one collection of mongodb one by one and save the API (using the npm request module) results in another collection($out).

**My Efforts**
I simply tried to take out the values one by one in async/await and send requests one by one

```
let data = await models.myCollection.find();
```

and send the data array request one by one through the iterative statement like the below code.

```
for( let i = 0 ; i < data.length ; i++ ) {
  await request(...);
}
```

The number of documents in the collection is about 1500.

**Expectation**
When I proceed as above, There's no error.
But I'm wondering about what would be an efficient logic.
(I think it would be better if I had a sample.)

Thank you.

Comment: How about  : await Promise.all(data.map(request))

Answer (score 0):

While I’ve not tried this approach before please verify my approach and question it. My recommendation would be to use `streams`. I have used it before for transformation of data in large JSON files.

You can refer to some documentation here: https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/tutorials/streams/

A good NPM module to handles streams that has worked for me is `RxJS`. It has observable and subscriber pattern which is easy to grasp. Ref: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS

For your example if it were to scale to millions or thousands of records, you could just process each document as it comes and call the API. Even better would be to batch the requests, where you fetch in multiples of 100s or 1000s and call the API once to update all the records.